# Cabal installing libraries give conflicting ghc-boot

Tags: windows, haskell, ghc, cabal

I had to reinstall ghc on windows. After this succeeded, I am unable to install packages using cabal. I have done cabal install cabal-install. I can run tests, and build. However, installing any package results in the following error;

[image: Error message Cabal]

I guess that somewhere some version is expected, but that this is not updated after reinstalling ghc.

I tried to reinstall cabal, and to reinstall packages as well.

For the full output;

```
`cabal install optparse-applicative --lib
Wrote tarball sdist to <redacted>\dist-newstyle\sdist\vc-0.1.0.0.tar.gz
Resolving dependencies...
cabal-3.6.2.0.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] next goal: directory (user goal)
[__0] rejecting: directory-1.3.8.1, directory-1.3.8.0 (constraint from user   
target requires ==1.3.7.1)
[__0] trying: directory-1.3.7.1
[__1] next goal: ghc-boot (user goal)
[__1] rejecting: ghc-boot-9.6.1, ghc-boot-9.6.0.20230302, ghc-boot-9.4.1      
(constraint from user target requires ==9.2.5)
[__1] rejecting: ghc-boot-9.2.5/installed-9.2.5 (conflict: directory==1.3.7.1,
ghc-boot => directory==1.3.6.2/installed-1.3.6.2)
[__1] rejecting: ghc-boot-9.2.2, ghc-boot-9.2.1, ghc-boot-9.0.1,
ghc-boot-8.8.3, ghc-boot-8.8.1, ghc-boot-8.6.5, ghc-boot-8.6.4,
ghc-boot-8.6.1, ghc-boot-8.4.4, ghc-boot-8.4.3, ghc-boot-8.4.2,
ghc-boot-8.4.1, ghc-boot-8.2.2, ghc-boot-8.2.1, ghc-boot-8.0.2, ghc-boot-8.0.1
(constraint from user target requires ==9.2.5)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: directory, ghc-boot)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: directory, ghc-boot`
```

Comment: Is the command you're using `cabal install --lib`?

Comment: Include any error messages (or code) as text boxes, not as screenshots. And yeah, definitely also include what commands you used and so on.

Comment: Hm. What's the user target that's demanding `directory ==1.3.7.1`? Can you change it to demand `directory ==1.3.6.2` (or something more semantic like `directory ^>=1.3`) instead?

Comment: This is for any library/module that I want to install; e.g. cabal install optparse-applicative --lib. I have updated the question.

Comment: @someStudentCS you can try to start from a clean state: `rm -rf ~/.ghc ~/.cabal && cabal update` and then your command. Note, that a safer version of the command you're running would be to specifically use a local, rather than (implicit) global environment: `cabal install --lib --package-env=. optparse-applicative`. In most cases you don't need `cabal install --lib` at all: depending on your goals, either create a cabal package depending on the library in question (e.g. `cabal init -nm`) or for playing with it in `ghci` do `cabal repl -b optparse-applicative`.

Comment: Also, I suggest you update your cabal to version 3.10 or at least 3.8.